# SWIG Use numpy.int64 as int for c++ function

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I am trying to use SWIG to generate a python wrapper and I am running into an issue where I am unable to use numpy data types with my c++ functions. I have boiled it down to a fairly minimal example:

my_cpp_function.h:

```
int foo(int x_i, int y_i);
```

my_cpp_function.cpp:

```
#include "my_cpp_function.h" 

int foo(int bar, int baz){
    return bar + baz;
}
```

my_cpp_function.i:

```
%module my_cpp_function

%{
    #include "my_cpp_function.h"
%}

%include "my_cpp_function.h"
```

Compiled as follows:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c my_cpp_function.cpp
$ swig -c++ -python my_cpp_function.i
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c -fPIC my_cpp_function_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python3.5 -I/usr/lib/python3.5
$ g++ -std=c++11  -shared -Wl,-soname,_my_cpp_function.so -o _my_cpp_function.so my_cpp_function.o my_cpp_function_wrap.o
```

Then in python3:

```
>>> from my_cpp_function import foo
>>> foo(1,2) 
3
>>> import numpy as np
>>> test = np.array([1,2])
>>> foo(test[0], test[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: in method 'cost', argument 1 of type 'int'
>>> foo(test[0].item(), test[1].item())
3
```

So it seems to be unhappy with the `numpy.int64`. I have seen that there is a numpy.i for using numpy with SWIG but I can't figure out how to use it in this case? Maybe I don't even need it, I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated!